# query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Tags: hibernate, join, fetch

I'm selecting two id columns but get error specified:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: **query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list** 

[FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=r,role=null,tableName=REVISIONS,tableAlias=revision1_,origin=ENTITY_CHANGED_IN_REVISION entitychan0_,columns={entitychan0_.REV_ID ,className=ru.csbi.registry.domain.envers.Revision}}] [ select ec.id as entityChangeId, r.id as revisionId from ru.csbi.registry.domain.envers.EntityChange as ec  inner join fetch ec.revision as r  where ec.groupEntityId = :groupEntityId and ec.groupName = :groupName  and r.timestamp < :entityDateFrom  and r.timestamp > :entityDateTo  and (        ec.revisionType in (0, 5, 1, 4, 2 )       and not ( ec.otherGroupEntityModified = false and ec.thisGroupEntityModified = true and ec.rowDataModified = false and ec.collectionOfNotGroupEntityModified = false   )      )  group by ec.id, r.id  having count(*) > :start order by r.id desc]
```

Some code:

```
String hql = " select ec.id as entityChangeId, r.id as revisionId from EntityChange as ec " +
            " inner join fetch ec.revision as r " +
            " where ec.groupEntityId = :groupEntityId" +
            " and ec.groupName = :groupName " +
            " and r.timestamp < :entityDateFrom " +
            " and r.timestamp > :entityDateTo " +
            " and ( " +
            "       ec.revisionType in (" + 
                        RevisionType.ADD.getRepresentation() + ", " + 
                        RevisionType.ONLY_DATA_PROPERTY_MOD.getRepresentation() + ", " +
                        RevisionType.BOTH_COLLECTION_AND_PROPERTY_MOD.getRepresentation() + ", " +
                        RevisionType.ONLY_COLLECTION_PROPERTY_MOD.getRepresentation() + ", " +
                        RevisionType.DEL.getRepresentation() +
                    " ) " +
            "     and not ( "+
                    "ec.otherGroupEntityModified = false and " +
                    "ec.thisGroupEntityModified = true and " +
                    "ec.rowDataModified = false and " +
                    "ec.collectionOfNotGroupEntityModified = false " +
                "  ) " +
            "     ) " +
            " group by ec.id, r.id " +
            " having count(*) > :start" +
            " order by r.id desc";
```

How to fix the error and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: for future searchers of this question, in my situation, i was joining a non lazy attribute. When i remove joining clause it was solved.

Comment: I think in your case the problem is that you do not select the whole entity (EntityChange) but only a few columns. Fetch clause makes only sense, if the root entity is selected and you want a mapped collection / entitiy to be filled by joining it.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use regular `join` instead of `join fetch` (by the way, it's `inner` by default):

```
String hql = " select ec.id as entityChangeId, r.id as revisionId from EntityChange as ec " + 
        " join ec.revision as r " + ...
```

As error message tells you, `join fetch` doesn't make sense here, because it's a performance hint that forces eager loading of collection.

Comment: Just to clarify,  `join fetch` can also be used to force the eager loading of an association such as a field annotated with @ManyToOne and not just collections.

Comment: Hm.. I'm facing a similar issue, but I do need to do the join fetch to avoid n+1 problem

Comment: @levgen,  I don't know details of your query but, keep in mind that count query should not have "fetch" at all. https://codingexplained.com/coding/java/spring-framework/fetch-query-not-working-spring-data-jpa-pageable#comment-293535

Comment: @levgen It's hard to help you without seeing a code, but if it happens that you use Spring Data with `@Query` annotation, then you can specify separate queries for fetching and count: see [this question (Spring-Data FETCH JOIN with Paging is not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21549480/1429387) for details.

Comment: Should I use EntityChange entity as result object or some other POJO with 2 columns?

Comment: Removing "fetch" led me to N+1 problem and caused everything in my application to hang. Would not recommend this solution to anyone.

Comment: This is not a solution for the problem as the author wanted a join fetching to probably avoid n+1 issue.

Comment: Use the answer below(add count query).This solution leads to an n+1 issue.

Comment: In contrast to what others commented, this didn't lead to N+1 additional queries for my solution. The join worked and only one query was executed. Not sure, though, if there is something else in my code that helped with that.

Answer (score 80):

As you need the `join fetch`, removing the `fetch` won't meet your needs.

What you should do instead is specify a count query together with it.

Assuming you are paginating the result, below is a JPA query that takes id as a `param` and will cause the problem you specified and the second query solves this by adding count query to it.

Note: `fk_field` is the attribute in `tableA` that has the *one-to-many* rln. The count query does not use `join fetch`.

```
@Query(value = "from TableA a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.fk_field where a.id = :id") 

@Query(value = "from TableA a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.fk_field where a.id = :id", 
  countQuery = " select  count(a) from TableA a left join a.fk_field where a.id = :id")
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer if you want to keep FETCH and avoid n+1. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me. Don't know why hibernate cannot do this automatically.

Comment: The other answer from axtavt leads to N+1 problem. This is the right answer!

Comment: Is there a way to achieve a similar solution when using `public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<T> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder)` defined in `Specification<T>`??

Answer (score 12):

Not relevant to OP's specific query, but for me same `query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list` error was thrown due to incorrect `JOIN FETCH` syntax of a nested relation, it must be referenced via an alias whereas I intuitively tried to refer to it via full path.

Bad: (causes `not present in the select list` error)

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA a
JOIN FETCH a.relationB
JOIN FETCH a.relationB.relationC
```

Good: (works!)

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableA a
JOIN FETCH a.relationB AS b
JOIN FETCH b.relationC
```

Hope that helps someone

Comment: Yes! This did the trick. Oh my god, I was stuck for hours on this.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has relation with the N+1 problem on Spring Data, if you would reach to use JpaSpecificationExecutor, you can solve it you could change *Page* to *Slice*, review this input, please: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637545/how-to-solve-the-n1-problem-in-spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your related item column into selection clause

```
select ec.id as entityChangeId, r.id as revisionId, **r.revision** 
from EntityChange as ec " +
        " inner join fetch ec.revision as r " +
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Spring JPA, then this query should fix it for you

`@Query( value = “FROM TableName t LEFT JOIN FETCH t.columnName WHERE t.columnName = value”, countQuery = “select count(t) from TableName t left join t.columnName WHERE t.columnName = value”)`

Note the where clause can be removed to you don’t have what you are filtering by