# Convert an SQL Query that includes join fetch to a Criteria Hibernate query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to convert the following query:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from TestEntity te " +
                    "join fetch te.someEntity se " +  
                    "left join fetch te.someEntity2 se2 "
                    "left join fetch se2.someEntity3 " +
                    "where se.predicateHere =:prediacte");
```

to a Criteria Hibernate Query, but definitely missing something because I am getting the following error:

```
query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list
```

When I try this:

```
Root<TestEntity> testEntityRoot = criteria.from(TestEntity.class);
testEntityRoot.fetch(TestEntity_.someEntity, JoinType.INNER);
testEntityRoot.fetch(TestEntity_.someEntity2, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(SomeEntity2.someEntity3, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Sorry about the table/column naming, but it's sensitive data.

Comment: Please try after removing `fetch ` from your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459779/query-specified-join-fetching-but-the-owner-of-the-fetched-association-was-not)

Comment: @kamleshpandey I tried, and it doesn't work. When I return the JSON result to the front end, it complains about the session not being open.

Comment: @PeterŠály I don't think it is, because that didn't solve my issue. I am building a criteria query, and not an SQL query :)

Comment: @cpu_meltdown next time put entity source code in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue using this same query:

```
Root<TestEntity> testEntityRoot = criteria.from(TestEntity.class);
testEntityRoot.fetch(TestEntity_.someEntity, JoinType.INNER);
testEntityRoot.fetch(TestEntity_.someEntity2, JoinType.LEFT).fetch(SomeEntity2.someEntity3, JoinType.LEFT);
```

Except that I was fetching entities in the wrong order.

First we need to fetch the root entity, and then chain any fetches to get to the the one we want.