# How to solve the N+1 problem in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using Spring Data JPA as the persistence layer and I'm facing the N+1 problem. I'm also using the Specifications API because of which I'm finding difficult to solve N+1 problem. Please help.

```
@Entity
public class PopulationHealth {

    @Id
    private int caseId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "caseId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CostSaving> costSavings;
}
```

```
public class CostSaving {

    @Id
    private int caseId;
}
```

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface PopulationHealthRepository extends JpaRepository<PopulationHealth, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<PopulationHealth> {

    Page<PopulationHealth> findAll(Specification<PopulationHealth> spec, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In the below class, the root.join() method, I added this later, this creates the left join in the query but, N+1 problem still happens. Please refer to below log output:

```
public class PopulationHealthSearchSpec implements Specification<PopulationHealth> {

    private List<PopulationHealthCriteriaDto> criteria;

    public PopulationHealthSearchSpec() {
        criteria = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCriteria(List<PopulationHealthCriteriaDto> criteria) {
        this.criteria.addAll(criteria);
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<PopulationHealth> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        criteria.forEach(p -> {
            SearchOperation operation = p.getOperation();
            root.join("costSavings", JoinType.LEFT);
            switch (operation) {
                case GREATER_THAN:
                    predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), convertToDate(p.getValue())));
                    break;
                case GREATER_THAN_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), convertToDate(p.getValue())));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    predicates.add(cb.lessThan(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), convertToDate(p.getValue())));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), convertToDate(p.getValue())));
                    break;
                case EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), p.getValue()));
                    break;
                case NOT_EQUAL:
                    predicates.add(cb.notEqual(root.get(p.getKey().toString()), p.getValue()));
                    break;
                case IN:
                    predicates.add(getInPredicates(cb, root, p));
                    break;
                case NOT_IN:
                    predicates.add(getInPredicates(cb, root, p).not());
                    break;
            }
        });
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

Log Output with N+1 queries. The first query has a Left join But still there is N+1 problem.

```
2020-05-06 19:46:41,527 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : select population0_.CaseId as CaseId1_3_, population0_.CaseCreateDate as CaseCrea2_3_ from POPULATION_HEALTH_UNMASKED population0_ left outer join COST_SAVINGS costsaving1_ on population0_.CaseId=costsaving1_.CaseId where population0_.CaseId in (3098584 , 3098587 , 3098591) order by population0_.CaseCreateDate asc limit ?
2020-05-06 19:46:41,709 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : select costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_0_, costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_1_ from COST_SAVINGS costsaving0_ where costsaving0_.CaseId=?
2020-05-06 19:46:41,744 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : select costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_0_, costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_1_ from COST_SAVINGS costsaving0_ where costsaving0_.CaseId=?
2020-05-06 19:46:41,781 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL : select costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_0_, costsaving0_.CaseId as CaseId1_1_1_ from COST_SAVINGS costsaving0_ where costsaving0_.CaseId=?
```

After using the fetch() instead of a join() in the Specification class, I get below issue:

```
2020-05-06 20:29:25,315 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.PopulationHealth.costSavings,tableName=COST_SAVINGS,tableAlias=costsaving1_,origin=POPULATION_HEALTH_UNMASKED population0_,columns={population0_.CaseId ,className=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.CostSaving}}] [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.PopulationHealth as generatedAlias0 left join fetch generatedAlias0.costSavings as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias0.caseCreateDate>:param0]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.PopulationHealth.costSavings,tableName=COST_SAVINGS,tableAlias=costsaving1_,origin=POPULATION_HEALTH_UNMASKED population0_,columns={population0_.CaseId ,className=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.CostSaving}}] [select count(generatedAlias0) from com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.PopulationHealth as generatedAlias0 left join fetch generatedAlias0.costSavings as generatedAlias1 where generatedAlias0.caseCreateDate>:param0]] with root cause
org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias1,role=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.PopulationHealth.costSavings,tableName=COST_SAVINGS,tableAlias=costsaving1_,origin=POPULATION_HEALTH_UNMASKED population0_,columns={population0_.CaseId ,className=com.cambia.mmt.cdqs.api.entity.CostSaving}}]
```

Comment: But its just plain JPA so you can eg join fetch relation since `root` is avalilable to you so instead of `join` use `fetch`. I think that something else is processing the result (result serialization eg?) and that is causing relations to be initialized

Comment: When I use fetch instead of a join, for some reason, in the Specification class, in the switch statement, GREATER_THAN condition breaks. It gives me the below error - org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [...]

Comment: As far I know you  can't fetch child when you use specification and join doesn't mean it will fetch data.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Spring-Data can do any better here since it tries to do a count query first in order to provide the total count information in the Page object. You could use `Slice` to avoid the count query.

If you want something more advanced you can take a look at the [Blaze-Persistence integration with Spring-Data](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-integration). It will use a different pagination mechanism that allows this to work and is also more efficient. Using Entity-Views will even give you an additional performance boost.