# Join fetch for nested collections

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have an entity structure as follows:

```
E1
  List<E2> e2s; //OneToMany relation

E2
  E3 e3;
    E4 e4
      List<E5> e5s; //OneToMany relation
```

All the collections are lazy loaded by default. I'd like to define a JPA query to eager fetch the E5 list located in deeper levels of E1.

I tried queries like:

```
"SELECT e1 FROM E1 e1" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.e2s AS e2s" +
            " JOIN e2s.e3 AS e3" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e3.e4.e5s";

"SELECT e1 FROM E1 e1" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.e2s AS e2s" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e2s.e3.e4.e5s";
```

Results in `query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list` error.

```
"SELECT e1 FROM E1 e1" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.e2s.e3.e4.e5s";
```

Results in `illegal attempt to dereference collection [e1.e2s]` error

```
"SELECT e1 FROM E1 e1" +
            " LEFT JOIN FETCH e1.e2s AS e2s" +
            " JOIN e2s.e3 AS e3" +
            " JOIN e3.e4.e5s";
```

This does not initialize the `e5s` collection.

Using `Hibernate JPA 2.1`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459779/query-specified-join-fetching-but-the-owner-of-the-fetched-association-was-not)

Comment: No, it does not. I've added an additional case that I tried. It did not initialize the collection that I'm expecting to be initialized.

Comment: I have never seen you explicitly do `JOIN e3.e4 AS e4`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But there are other queries that I chain the fields without such explicit joins like `e2s.e3.e4.e5`. But never used such phrases in a `JOIN FETCH`

Comment: `e1.e2s` is a collection, not an E2, so you can't do `e1.e2s.e3`, it would make no sense.

Comment: @MauricePerry, yes, actually, you're right. Just tried them out. In 1st and 4th cases, I tried to get a reference to `E2` instances by an explicit join but still could not initialize the `E5` list.